# ScriptEngine with name "nashorn" is null

Tags: java, java-6, java-scripting-engine

I'm trying to create `ScriptEngine` with name `"nashorn"`:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
if (engine == null) {
     System.out.println("engine == null");
}
```

But I always get

```
engine == null
```

Why is this happening? The docs say:

> The Nashorn engine is the default ECMAScript (JavaScript) engine
>   bundled with the Java SE Development Kit (JDK).

It means that the Nashorn engine is the default engine and must be present in JDK, don't it?

Comment: Which JRE are you using to execute your program ?

Comment: @Berger, I'm using JDK 1.6.0_25 version with the attached JRE.

Comment: Also you can list all engines, or get engine by type: js.

Comment: Nashorn is available since Java 8.

Comment: @Ksenia : Nashorn seems available only since JDK 1.8  :  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a small snippet to list all supported engines

```
public class Script {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js")
           .eval("print('Hello from Java\\n');");
        for (ScriptEngineFactory se : new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories()) {
            System.out.println("se = " + se.getEngineName());
            System.out.println("se = " + se.getEngineVersion());
            System.out.println("se = " + se.getLanguageName());
            System.out.println("se = " + se.getLanguageVersion());
            System.out.println("se = " + se.getNames());
        }
    }
}
```

Java 6 (1.6.0_43)

```
Hello from Java
se = Mozilla Rhino
se = 1.6 release 2
se = ECMAScript
se = 1.6
se = [js, rhino, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
```

Java 7 (1.7.0_40)

```
Hello from Java                                                  
se = Mozilla Rhino                                               
se = 1.7 release 3 PRERELEASE                                    
se = ECMAScript                                                  
se = 1.8                                                         
se = [js, rhino, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
```

Java 8 (1.8.0_74)

```
Hello from Java

se = Oracle Nashorn
se = 1.8.0_74
se = ECMAScript
se = ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1
se = [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem despite actually using Java 8.

To get it working, replace

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
```

With the following:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
```

The reason the latter worked is mentioned in the following javadoc:

> This constructor loads the implementations of ScriptEngineFactory visible to the given ClassLoader using the service provider mechanism.

> If loader is null, the script engine factories that are bundled with the platform and that are in the usual extension directories (installed extensions) are loaded.